# tomcat cookie domain validation

Tags: tomcat, cookies

I'm using tomcat 8.0.21 with the new Rfc6265 cookie processor. If there are cookies starting with a dot I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An invalid domain [.db-app.de] was specified for this cookie
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor.validateDomain(Rfc6265CookieProcessor.java:180)
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor.generateHeader(Rfc6265CookieProcessor.java:122)
org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.generateCookieString(Response.java:959)
org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.addCookie(Response.java:907)
org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.addCookie(ResponseFacade.java:392)
org.esigate.servlet.impl.ResponseSender.sendResponse(ResponseSender.java:70)
com.bahn.esiExtensions.ExtendedProxyServlet.doFilter(ExtendedProxyServlet.java:104)
```

Is there a way to prevent tomcat from throwing this error?

Answer (score 12):

I'm using a new version of Tomcat 8 (from this last October) and after add the line to force use the legacy cookie processor, it works fine.
 On your `${catalina.base}conf/context.xml`:

```
<Context>

<!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
<!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
<!--
<Manager pathname="" />
-->

<!-- Force use the old Cookie processor (because this new tomcat version uses RFC6265 Cookie Specification) -->
<CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcessor" />
```

I hope this may be your case. Just set this CookieProcessor, and your implementation will be working as was in previous versions of Tomcat 8.

Answer (score 5):

With the new cookie processor on Tomcat 8, your cookie domain must start with a number or a letter. Removing the leading dot should get rid of this error.

Try changing it to `dot.db-app.de` instead, or give it a new name entirely.

Comment: Hi, why do you suggest `dot.db-app.de`? Is the `dot` st specific to Tomcat 8? I tested with Tomcat 9 and setting just `db-app.de` should be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can revert Tomcat's behaviour by defining the legacy cookie processor in your context.xml file.

See [Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference: The Cookie Processor Component](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/cookie-processor.html)