# Servlet.service() throwing illegal argument exception

Tags: java, spring, servlets, tomcat8

I am deploying my project on tomcat8 and when i hit localhost:8080 on my browser, it is saying internal server error. I found this trace in local host logs

```
27-Dec-2016 14:17:20.592 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [] threw exception
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An invalid domain [.test.com] was specified for this cookie
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor.validateDomain(Rfc6265CookieProcessor.java:183)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor.generateHeader(Rfc6265CookieProcessor.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.generateCookieString(Response.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.addCookie(Response.java:937)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.addCookie(ResponseFacade.java:386)
    at com.snapdeal.rms.web.utils.CookieManager.setCookie(CookieManager.java:25)
    at com.snapdeal.rms.web.utils.CookieManager.setCookie(CookieManager.java:17)
    at com.snapdeal.rms.web.filter.RequestIdentifierFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestIdentifierFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1437)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here test.com is a valid site. Could not find what cookie it was referring to

Comment: I think it is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608550/tomcat-cookie-domain-validation