# Use SpringBoot 3 with older version of Tomcat (10.0) for legacy cookie configuration starting with a dot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, cookies

We have an existing authenticaton microservice that uses MS Azure as authentication provider with SSO.
It currently uses SpringBoot 2.7, and we need to update that to SB 3.x

The trouble is that when user authenticates, that creates a browser-side JSESSIONID cookie that starts with a '.' (dot), as in `.domain.name`

That creates the need for using `LegacyCookieProcessor` as per [tomcat cookie domain validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608550/tomcat-cookie-domain-validation).

The `LegacyCookieProcessor` has been removed in Tomcat version 10.1,so upgrading to SB 3 breaks the application - it starts complaining of invalid cookie domain.

**What I tried:**

I had an idea to upgrade SB to v.3 but pin the tomcat version down to 10.0, as below:

pol.xml:

```
...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
    </parent>
...
    <tomcat.version>10.0.27</tomcat.version>
...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
...
```

The `jakarta.servlet-api` dependency was required since otherwise the `jakarta.servlet.ServletConnection` class wasn't found in my tests.

Controller method:

```
  @Operation(
      summary = "Deletes a session for the user",
      responses = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Success - session is deleted"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Not Found - session is not found")
      })
  @DeleteMapping("/logout")
  @ResponseBody
  @ResponseStatus(OK)
  public AuthDetailsResponse<String> logout(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    authService.logOut(request);
    handleLogOutResponse(request, response);
    return new AuthDetailsResponse<>(OK, propertiesConfig.getAadLogoutUrl());
  }
```

**What else I've tried:**

I have also tried to use the spring-boot-starter-tomcat

```
...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.16</version> <!-- this pins tomcat version to 9.x -->
    </dependency>
```

In both cases, that starts my server nicely but the controller is never invoked. The client gets a 404 error on trying to invoke the `/logout` endpoint

So, the questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong in the above confoguration?
2. Is there an alternative way of handling the legacy domains with a dot in SB 3?

Comment: How do you invoke `/logout`?  It has a `@DeleteMapping`.

Comment: I believe that is invoked as part of a callback from Azure, but that invoking that is not an issue - it's invoked all right in the old version of application with SB 2.7

Comment: I think that your question mixes two different problems: the invalid cookie is created during login (or earlier, at the first user access), the 404 is related to logout.